# Rails query to SQL statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to write an write this:

```
Team.last.players.sum("goals")
```

erb:

```
SELECT SUM("players"."goals") 
FROM "players" 
WHERE "players"."team_id" = $1  [["team_id", 2]]
```

how to rewrite this so that I could use it in a method:

```
def sql_search
  sql = "SELECT SUM \"players\".\"goals\" FROM \"players\" WHERE \"players\".\"team_id\" = $1 [[\"team_id\", #{self.id}"
  connection.execute(sql);
end
```

keep getting this error:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: SELECT SUM "players"."goals" FROM "players" WHERE "players"....
```

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `\"` in sql statement, just remove them.

```
def sql_search
    sql = "SELECT sum(goals) FROM players WHERE team_id = #{self.id};"
    connection.execute(sql);
end
```

Comment: This seems right but a little explanation could help

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason that you want to hard code the SQL query? It's generally bad practice to use string interpolation to insert parameters to SQL queries because of [SQL injection attacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection). Instead it's recommended to use ActiveRecord's SQL query parameter binding like this:

```
user_input = 5
Player.where('team_id = ?', user_input).sum(:goals)
```

Basically what this does is insert the parameter `5` after sanitization. This means you're safe from attacks where a hacker attempts to insert arbitrary SQL into parameter variables attempting to return sensitive data or delete data entirely!